# problems adding 2 characters together in c

Tags: c, character-encoding

I'm currently trying to add 2 characters in c i.e.

```
char a = 127;
char b = 127;
char c = a + b;

printf("%d\n", c);
```

which prints out 4294967278, I'm actually having problems anytime I add 2 numbers together where the resultant ASCII value would be greater than 127, what is happening here? aren't characters 8 bits or 256 possible numbers? so adding values that would be less than 256 should work no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because your `char`s are `signed` and can hold values from -128 to 127. By using

```
char c = a + b;
```

you have an overflow and overflow of `signed char` results in Undefined Behavior. You can use an `unsigned char` to get rid of the problem:

```
unsigned char c = a + b;
```

Comment: thank you! that was a silly one!, I'll accept your answer when it lets me in 9 mins or so, i had previously set c to unsinged char but the a+b was till causing issues, it appears a, and b both had to be as well thanks!

Comment: Also, there is some issue in relation to variadic functions (like `printf(3)` is) in which all `char` are automatically cast to `(int)` and all `unsigned char` are cast to `(unsigned)` before being passed to the function.