# when i do printf("%d",'='+'=');, why it is showing 122.Please explain in details

Tags: c, character-encoding

```
main()
{
char a1='=';
char a2='=';
printf("%d",a1+a2);
}
```

Code is as above , it simply perform '='+'=' and printing the value 122.(why??)..

Comment: figure out what the numerical representation for `'='` is and that should give you a start in figuring this out.

Comment: What kind of output were you expecting?

Comment: why is this downvoted? This is a genuine question.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso possibly because of 'Please explain in details' and the OP has made no effort to explain, or investigate, why it's adding together two chars - homework tells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problems adding 2 characters together in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274708/problems-adding-2-characters-together-in-c)

Comment: @JSTL no, that one has the problem of *undefined behaviour*, which is not present in this.

Comment: @Jay Prajapati please accept an answer if it helped solve your problem, or comment to ask for clarification on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, characters are represented internally using ascii. Characters are just numeric types, so adding them just adds the ascii* values. (Google `ASCII` for more info on this.)

In ascii, `'='` is `61`, so `'=' + '='` is the same as `61 + 61`, or `122`, which is what you're getting.

If you were hoping that `+` would concatenate `a1` and `a2`, unfortunately that's not the case, since `char`s are numeric values in C. If this is what you want, I'd google `C strings` (for how C handles strings) as a starting point.

If you were expecting it to do something else, I can edit my answer to explain that as well.

*EDIT: as pointed out by Fei Xiang, ASCII is not guaranteed by the C standard. However, on most modern systems, ASCII is used, and a similar answer to mine applies to your program regardless of the encoding used.

Comment: Although very likely, it's not guaranteed that ASCII will be used.

Comment: @FeiXiang you're right, but I didn't want to get too much into encodings when the OP didn't even know that `char` was a numeric type. Edited to make note of this.

Answer (score 1):

Because ASCII value of `'='` is `61`

[ASCII Values](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html)